# Check if variable is boolean

Tags: php

I've inherited a really old system that interacts with many others and have to rewrite it as REST whilst maintaining compatibility with the older clients.

One of the possible inputs it receives is supposedly BOOL, but in practice, many of the existing clients use [1,"T","true","TRUE","verdadero",...] so I've written up a function that checks a bunch of these (I'm also logging all queries in case  I have to add any later), the problem is it seems to work randomly; sometimes it gives me not BOOL, sometimes TRUE and sometimes FALSE, for the life of me I can't figure out what I've done wrong.

For example, "aaaaa" evaluates to FALSE, while "AAAAA" evaluates to TRUE.

```
function verBool($data) {
    $sale = "KO";
    $aceptados_true = array(1,"1","V","T","v","t","true","True","TRUE","verdadero","Verdadero","VERDADERO");
    $aceptados_false = array(0,"0","F","f","false","False","FALSE","falso","Falso","FALSO");
    if(in_array($data,$aceptados_true)) { $sale = "1"; }
    if(in_array($data,$aceptados_false)) { $sale = "0"; }
    return $sale;
}
```

Comment: How does it return true? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5abbfba3e491f66cb6046f6e22f86479a4d3ac56

Comment: @Akintunde you have read only the title. Read the question body too. The OP clearly states that the input value is not a boolean but a string.

Comment: This seems like a good way to break an application, and confuse those two write it and those who reads it. But I can't reproduce that output you've shown: https://3v4l.org/TLYRF - although you should probably make it case-insensitive, instead of checking for `falso` and `Falso` and then `FALSO`.

Comment: Put in the arrays of possible values only lowercase strings and search for [`strtolower($data)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) in them. Now it fails to identify a mixed-case value (`TRue`, for example). Also, [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the input value before searching it in the lists.

Comment: If you passed `aaaaa` it would not return FALSE it would return `KO`, and the same for `AAAAA`, and your function should only return true or false boolean not a string `0`, `1` or what even `KO` means.

Comment: And why allow the user to type true/false themselves? This should be controlled by the application - so it could for example be a select-dropdown with true and false, and the application sets variables to boolean instead. Users are generally stupid, assume they don't know anything and assume they do things that break your application.

Comment: I'm using "KO" as my check; as in "system has entered something unforeseen"; and I can't error out if not truly BOOL, this is in-use and I _have_ to respect current "working" systems; sadly that's a by-product of inheriting code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say exactly what's wrong until I don't see input data.
But try to

1. Add `true` and `false` values to your arrays respectively
2. Remove case-sensitive values from your arrays (leave lowercase values only)
3. Check if `is_string($data)` and set the `$data` value to `strtolower($data)` in this case
4. Set the third argument of `in_array` to true ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php))
5. Optionally add logging of input value and result for future analysis (i. e. `fputcsv($log, [$data, $result])`, see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fputcsv.php))

Comment: This was it, type checking on in_array was messing me up.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that's a case-sensitive issue or not with your aaaaa and AAAAA example. If that's the case, you can try using pre_grep() insensitive:

```
<?php 
function verBool($data) {
    $sale = "KO";
    $aceptados_true = array(1,"1","V","T","v","t","true","True","TRUE","verdadero","Verdadero","VERDADERO");
    $aceptados_false = array(0,"0","F","f","false","False","FALSE","falso","Falso","FALSO");
    if(preg_grep("/".$data."/i",$aceptados_true)) { $sale = "1"; }
    if(preg_grep("/".$data."/i",$aceptados_false)) { $sale = "0"; }
    return $sale;
}

echo verBool('verDadero');
?>
```